# SQLite getting ArrayList to display in a textview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, arraylist, textview

I'm having trouble getting my ArrayList from my SQLite database to display in a textview. The idea is to make it a "history" page so users can see their past entries. When I do `tv.setText(db.getAllBalance)`, all I get is a crash and the logcat displays my projects package name followed by something like @4f58a392 over and over. This is my final step to complete my app, and it's struggling. Any assistance would be appreciated.

My database:

```
//Getting All Balance
public List<Balance> getAllBalance(){
    List<Balance> balanceList = new ArrayList<Balance>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BALANCE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Balance balance = new Balance();
            balance.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            balance.setAmount(cursor.getFloat(1));
            // Adding balance to list
            balanceList.add(balance);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return balanceList;
}
```

My history class:

```
public class History extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);

        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);

        Log.d("testing", "reading wallet " + db.getAllBalance());
        tv.setText((CharSequence) db.getAllBalance());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        AdView adview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        //re.setTesting(true);
        adview.loadAd(re);
    }
}
```

I have a bad history of posting "bad questions". But I promise, I searched and searched and just could not find the solution.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `List` in the `getAllBalance()`, and then you are casting it to a `CharSequence`. You can try to do a `toString()` call after `getAllBalance()` to try to get some `String` representation of the object. Remove the cast to `CharSequence`; `toString()` if you use `toString()'

Comment: That got me a little closer, but now I get this as my output. Is there a way to change this into actual words I can understand? lol. I just don't know what that means or where it comes from http://i1274.photobucket.com/albums/y440/Jon_Favale/Screenshot_2013-09-10-23-35-17_zps603e9b84.png?t=1378870585

Comment: That is what I mean by a "`String` representation of the `Object`" If you want to match the data the object contains with the columns it is a completely different approach

Comment: Hmm. Don't seem to understand too well. I guess what the code is doing is not getting the actual data in the tables but more of the objects of the data themselves? Would this need a change in the database code or more of a change within my history class to change this into data?

Comment: That code is giving you a readable description of the `Object`. It is telling you that it is an `Object` of the `Balance` `Class` and it is stored at a certain location in memory (what comes after the @). When I want to map stuff from a database to a list I use a `ListView` and an `Adapter`; SimpleCursorAdapter my be suitable for your case. Keep in mind that doing queries in the UI `Thread` may make your app non responsive. Using `Loaders` is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have no idea how to use any of those so I guess i'll just have to finish this later next week and ask my professor in the morning. Maybe she'll be able to show me.

Comment: What if instead of using the array list, I create a for loop that will insert the data one by one into an array and then display it? Sure it's probably a bad way to do it, but having something work is better than nothing.

Comment: Well, you can do that but you will have to manually space the data so it fits under the desired column. You will run into trouble in different screen sizes.

Comment: I'm thinking using 3 separate text views, one for each column may work. That way they all get aligned within the text view. Just need to have them skip to the next lines. I'll come back when I find a solution